# MATLAB Compiler debug

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB GUI I would like to "compile" using MATLAB Compiler.
Using MATLAB Compiler, the current path, file management change so I am not sure if my program works after deployment. Is it possible to debug my program to check if it works properly when deployed.

It would be great if there were a tool simulating the behavior of a deployed program from a M script.

Comment: You can test a program without using a debugger. Not sure what you're looking for. There are a few things that are different in "compiled" code, but I don't think file management is one of those, unless you are talking about accessing M-files as data instead of code.

Comment: By file management, I meant that the current path is different. In the compiled code, you have the current path for the executable but also the one for the extracted mfiles in a hidden local folder. I want to make sure I do not mess up with these paths, that's why I wanted to debug the program in a deployment mode.

Comment: I would use a virtual machine without matlab installed.